# jquery word length plugin instead of character length

Tags: jquery

Is there any plugin for jquery that counts the length of entered word...no matter how much words entered...

means that counting how much characters a word contain and limiting entered characters for each word...

So please let me know if you have solution for this...

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://roy-jin.appspot.com/jsp/textareaCounter.jsp

http://web.archive.org/web/20150318025849/http://www.jqeasy.com/jquery-character-counter/demo/

http://theproductguy.com/noblecount/noblecount.demo.html

http://wplayground.comuv.com/counter/

```
$('#word').keyup(
    function(){
        var words = $(this).val().split();          
        //then you have array of words, and porcess it
    }
)

<textarea id="word"></textarea>
```

Comment: but this plugin not counts characters for each word (and limiting word length) instead counting characters of whole text area....

Comment: @Muaz Khan Well why don't you try to make your own it might not be quite difficult